# Git support in iOS app

Tags: ios, git

I would like to build an iOS app that includes some basic Git functionality. I basically only need pull, commit, and push capabilities. I'm new to iOS development so I am not aware of any frameworks or libraries that could provide these capabilities. I'm not sure if GitHub has an API for these features but that would suffice too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let me answer this old question with [libgit2](http://libgit2.github.com) library and their [ObjectiveGit](https://github.com/libgit2/objective-git) wrapper.

> **libgit2** is a portable, pure C implementation of the Git core methods provided as a re-entrant linkable library with a solid API, allowing you to write native speed custom Git applications in any language which supports C bindings.

**ObjectiveGit** provides Cocoa bindings to the **libgit2** library. Even their licenses allow you to build closed-source software.

Answer (score 1):

Found a [random guide](http://swanson.github.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html) to making a commit with the API, no clue how accurate/useful it is.

Comment: I'm accepting this as the answer until a native solution can be provided.

Comment: And also, +1 because the app that the author is building is exactly the same as what I was thinking of building. So thanks for helping me find this one!

Answer (score 0):

GitHub API is available, details here : http://developer.github.com/

Comment: Yes, GitHub has an API, but I don't see anything in their documentation on how to do a pull, commit, or push which makes me think this type of thing is not supported from their API.

Comment: http://swanson.github.com/blog/2011/07/23/digging-around-the-github-api-take-2.html

Comment: @ellotheth that's the kind of GitHub API tutorial I was looking for. You should post it as your own answer.